# Cross domain cookie - shared data between domains

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, share, user-data

I have been looking for any solution for my case, but I haven't found it. Therefore I decided to share my solution.

**CASE**

I want to share some user information between domains. It means I want to get all collected info about user who already visited my **web1.com** last week and come to **web2.com** right now. The user is for first time at **web2.com** but I already know who he is.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

**Requirements:**

- PHP server - central server whose generate cookies and serve user data
- Database server (optionally) - keep cookies and user data (you can use file etc.) I'm using Postgres.
- Possibility to include part of JS code into webs.

**PHP server http://cookie-server.local index.php**:

```
<?php
$hash = array_key_exists('my-cookie', $_COOKIE) ? $_COOKIE["my-cookie"] : NULL;
try {
    $connection = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=cookie;host=localhost", 'postgres', 'postgres');
    $data = findHash($connection, $hash);
    if ($data) {
        setcookie('my-cookie', $data['hash'], strtotime("+1 year"));
        sendResponse($data);
    } else {
        $hash = generateHash();
        $data = storeHash($connection, $hash);
        setcookie('my-cookie', $hash, strtotime("+1 year")); 
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

function findHash($connection, $hash) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * from cookie WHERE hash = :hash';
    $stm = $connection->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $stm->execute(array(':hash' => $hash));
    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        printError($stm->errorInfo());
    }
    return count($result) > 0 ? $result[0] : NULL;
}

function sendResponse($data) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    echo 'showData('. json_encode($data) .');';
}

function printError($error) {
    echo 'SQL error: ' . $error[2];
    die();
}

function generateHash() {
    return $hash = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE));
}

function storeHash($connection, $hash) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cookie (id, hash) VALUES (nextval('cookie_id_seq'), :hash)";
    $stm = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stm->execute(['hash' => $hash]);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        printError($stm->errorInfo());
    }
    return [
        'id' => $connection->lastInsertId(),
        'hash' => $hash,
        'name' => ''
    ];
}
?>
```

Basic web page on **web1.com** (The JS code hast to be everywhere you need to know info about user)

```
<html>
    <body>
        WEB 1:<br> <span id="hash"></span>  
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showData(data) {
            document.getElementById('hash').innerHTML = "<br>ID: " + data.id + "<br>Hash: " + data.hash + "<br>Jmeno: " + data.name;
        }

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = 'application/javascript';
        script.src = "http://cookie-server.local";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cookie-server.local">
</html>
```

**Database:**

[image]

**How it works?**

When user visit **web1.com**, the JS code execute and include
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cookie-server.local">` to page head element. The browser try to download content of file and it execute PHP code on server. The server look at passed cookies and find out there is no **my-cookie**. Therefore it generate cookie hash, store it in database, set it to user (cookie with name "my-cookie" for domain cookie-server.local) and send user data with [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). For another request to server it find previously generated hash in database and only extends expiration and sends user data for sure. Since now, when this user open any other web page (web2.com...) with the JS code, you know who it is.